# PHP MySQL 'too many connections' issue - Cent OS

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

We have high con-current traffic on server setup, when the traffic crossing 100+/sec, we facing the 'too many connections' issue with PHP & MySQL. We have separate AWS nodes for Application(PHP - 5.4.34) and Database(MySQL - 5.5.40).

- In the MySQL we have 3500 max connections limit and also we adjusted
  the variables in MySQL.
- On the high traffic time, the DB node CPU utilization not exceeds 10%
  and RAM usage below 4GB. But still we are facing the connections
  issue with application node.
- Using the MyISAM engine for Database.
- Used the mysql_connect function and closed the connection on every page completion.
- We monitoring the DB with Monyog tool, in that there is no slow queries or queue's.

We googled for the solution, but still we didn't get any valuable solution on the issue.

**Edit:**
Here are further more details on our server setup, we are using the Apache prefork mpm and current mpm setup below.

StartServers       300
MinSpareServers    300
MaxSpareServers   350
ServerLimit      1000
MaxClients       1000
MaxRequestsPerChild  99999

**PHP Configuration:**
memory_limit : 2048
max_execution_time : 0
timeout : 15
keep_alive : 0ff
keep_alive_timeout : 5

**AWS EC2**
App Node :
Core : 8 vCPUs
CPU utilization : 89%
RAM : 2048MB out of 30.5GB
Connection : mysql_connect API

its consume more CPU utilization and low RAM usage.

**Edit:**(Updates)
We updated the connectivity API to PDO and implemented the changes in the package. With the test run, we found same issue again. With the PDO update, we changed the Apache configuration too.
**DB connection error:** SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.31.26.180' (99)

Comment: Is this error coming from apache/ngix or mysql ?

Comment: This error coming on apache application node

Comment: You need to increase your worker count in apache.

Comment: We got solution for the 'too many connections' issue, by changing the MySQL server variables. We increased the **'max_connect_errors'** variable. Now we facing the high CPU Utilization. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: That is a very weird error... It sounds like your server cannot handle the load that your website is generating which is why your CPU utilization is very high. High CPU utilization can also be caused by long running queries, you can check your slow query log for that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, one of your Apache processes is announcing that it can't connect to MySQL due to "too many connections."

3500 simultaneous connections is a very large number indeed. Your database server seems to be overprovisioned, and you're web-server constrained here.

Here's what you need to do.

First, try reducing, not increasing, your apache ThreadLimit  and ThreadsPerChild parameters. You want fewer, not more, apache / php threads trying to connect to your data base. What happens when you don't have enough apache threads? Your client requests go into the TCP `listen()` queue. There's no harm in that, because any free thread can consume requests from that queue.

You might also try cutting MaxRequestsPerChild to 100 or so. If this dramatically fixes the problem you have a connection leak somewhere.

Second, at the level of workload you have, you *must* use persistent (reusable) MySQL connections. To do this you'll need to switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO` apis. This is, without doubt, worth your trouble.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, let we try with PDO and with these changes.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/370150/server-crashing-too-many-connections

```
StartServers          2
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75 
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients           400
MaxRequestsPerChild  20000
```

Please update post with these values. It will aid in troubleshooting.

Your apache config looks a bit messed up.

You have way too many processes.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers

You need 1 per core. max 8 apache servers.

I would switch it to 4

Set Min Servers 4

Set Max servers 16

ServerLimit 16

Here is some info on MaxClients
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients

This is a ratelimit setting, I would set this to something reasonable. if you on avg get 100 rq/s i would likely set this to 400.

MaxRequestsPerChild also is a rate limit setting. I would set this to be no more than 200.

Comment: Posted our current apache setup, please go through and post your replies. Thanks

Comment: IT might be helpful to have you post the log where the error is being recorded. I am still not 100% sure if it's apache or mysql causing the error.

Comment: We checked with the error log and following error we found: 
**ERROR** - 2015-1-30 11:06:26 --> Severity: Warning  --> mysql_pconnect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip-123-3-10-46.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal' (99) ../../../mysql_driver.php 91
**ERROR** - 2015-1-30 11:06:26 --> Unable to connect to the database

Comment: I wouldn't use a host name to try and connect. Most places have internal IP addresses you can use. The only thing this error suggests is that the database server is unreachable.

Comment: We are using only the private IP's for DB connectivity.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the server is somehow maxing out on outgoing tcp connections...  See this : http://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server